# Checking whether the both approaches are correct or not

Tags: graph-theory

> Given $7$ points in the plane , no three are collinear , lets each of the line segments joining the points be coloured with one of two colours red or blue . Prove that no matter what configuration of colours is used there are always atleast three chromatic triangles present.                               I was using two different methods to get the claim :

- **First method** :.                      (Assuming we know the fact that for  six points no three collinear we have atleast 2 chromatic triangles when coloured with two colours ) then consider the $7$ points as $A,B,C,D...G$ , take the first six $A..F$ they have two chromatic triangles , now remove the vertex which makes the two chromatic triangles(common to both triangles) let that be $A$ , then removing it we are left with $B,C..G$ again six points so again atleast two chromatic triangles , so therefore we have **atleast 4** $>3$ chromatic triangles and we are done .      **For disjoint case** :say $ABC$ , $DEF$ forms two triangles then consider removing $A$ we have $BCDEFG$ , both triangles would be not having $A$ edge but might be that $DEF$ is the one here too, so atleast one more so in total atleast three triangles (chromatic) possible

> **Second method** :.                         From a vertex maximum pairs of edges originating from it and are not having same colour are $9$ (3 of each colour are present in maximum case) . Now so in total we have $9*7 = 63$ such pairs , so total number of non-chromatic triangles are $\frac{63}{2}$ since any one pair gives a unique triangle joining the ends of those two . But each is counted twice since triangle from between $i-j$ is contibuted in both originating from $i$ and originating from $j$ cases . So we have max $31$ non chromatic triangles possible ,since total triangles we can form are $\binom{7}{3} = 35$ therefore we have  $35-31$ = atleast $4$ chromatic triangles .

- My query is related to both as in firstly are both approaches are correct and in the second method ot should be $32$ non chromatic triangles or $31$? i am confused in that part too as i dont exactly know what $31.5$ would mean  . Also any other approach can be also posted if anyone wants to .

Comment: First method wrong. The two triangles might be disjoint.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more what you mean @ParclyTaxel ?

Comment: Ok i think i got what you mean say ABC , DEF forms two triangles then consider removing A we have BCDEFG , both triangles would be not having A edge but might be that DEF is the one here too, so atleast one more so in total atleast three triangles (chromatic) possible ?